# Installing Laravel 4 on Windows IIS Inetpub wwwroot

Tags: iis-7, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-blade

Having spent an entire day wrestling with this, could someone please explain how I can install Laravel on Windows ?

I have installed the very latest version of PHP 5.4 (using Windows Installer) and tested that with a simple site and that all works fine.

I have installed the latest version of Composer and that all installed perfectly.

When I run `composer create-project laravel/laravel` (as advised with the 5 Minute Setup), it installs all the files in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\laravel`.

If I then set up a simple "Hello World" Laravel website within `inetpub\wwwroot`, it just doesn't seem to detect Laravel and throws a `generic error`.

I can't use XAMMP because many of my clients have Windows hosting, so I would eventually have to deploy the website to the `inetpub\wwwroot` directory.

Do I need to copy the Laravel files to every new Laravel website that I develop ?

How do I set the default file within `web.config` ?

As much as I'd dearly love to start developing with Laravel, the configuration process on a Windows development machine is just prohibitively complicated.

I'd be really grateful for any help, advice and pointers that anyone could please offer.

Comment: I would suggest to stay away from the IIS server on this one. I would go as far as saying running this on Windows Hosting is a big "no, no". Get yourself a WAMP or XAMMP - or even Ubuntu Server running in VM Box.

Comment: Hi User789 Thanks for the reply. That is a real shame because many of my clients only have Windows hosting and I was really hoping to start using Laravel instead of ASP.Net MVC for some projects, but it's just presenting so many problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I've done this before and it worked alright.
What I would do is deploy my tests on a local server such as Wamp.
When you are ready for production, simply push it to your remote server and then make the webconfig changes corresponding to the .htaccess:

1. Define the website root as *installation-directory*/public
2. Inside the public folder, try this web.config

   ```
       <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <defaultDocument>
           <files>
               <clear />
               <add value="index.php" />
               <add value="default.aspx" />
               <add value="Default.htm" />
               <add value="Default.asp" />
               <add value="index.htm" />
               <add value="index.html" />
           </files>
       </defaultDocument>
       <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
       <rewrite>
           <rules>
               <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

Comment: Hi kJamesy. Thank you very much for your reply. Can I please ask how you installed Laravel ? Did you do it by running 'create-project laravel/laravel' within Composer, which placed all the files within 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\laravel' for me or did you copy all the Laravel files to your website within 'inetpub/wwwroot'. Many thanks again for your reply which I'm sure will be helpful to others in this situation.

Comment: I use a local server always. Wamp to be precise. Then upload the final product to the production server (Windows or Linux). Try running that command **in the directory** you want Laravel installed in. Remember you can always copy it to the location you want after it has installed.

Comment: Thanks very much kJamesy, you have been very helpful and I will try your suggestions. Many thanks again.

Comment: Hi kJamesy. With your help, I have finally managed to install Laravel 4 on Windows and get it working. Running the command within the directory definitely made the difference. Once again, many thanks indeed and I'm extremely grateful for your help.